# Change the div element background according to sensor reading

Tags: javascript, html, css, esp8266

I've been playing with ESP8266 and achieved some good-looking readings via DHT22 and BH1780 sensors to a single HTML page where I can only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript for the frontend. Short story I read the temperature humidity and the light intensity in the tent, where light intensity is mainly to determine if is day or night  for example LUX = 0 is night and LUX = 1 is day

My question: How and what to use in order to change each  `<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">` according to the sensor readings, or even change the fontawesome icon from `<i class="fas fa-sun" style="color:#ffef4C;"></i>` to `<i class="fas fa-moon" style="color:#AFE2FE;"></i>`

For example, if Temperature readings exceeds 50 degree alert-danger...

Any suggestions welcome, but please note We can't use PHP :(

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

 <div class="card-body text-center">
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <span class="h4"><i class="fas fa-thermometer-half" style="color:#059e8a;"></i>  Temperature</span> 
    <span class="h4" id="temperature">29</span>
    <sup class="units">&deg;C</sup>
  </div>
```

Backend Arduino code

```
 // Replaces placeholder with DHT values
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == "TEMPERATURE"){
    return String(t);
  }
  else if(var == "HUMIDITY"){
    return String(h);
  }
  else if(var == "LUX"){
    return String(lux);
  }
  return String();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

Replace

```
document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

with this

```
const div = document.getElementById("temperature"), 
     temp = +this.responseText; // cast to number
div.innerHTML = temp;
let color = "green"; // default
if (temp < 18) color = "blue";
else if (temp > 28) color = "red";
div.closest(".alert.alert-success").style.backgroundColor=color;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking you time :) I have edit few things like adding ; at the end of add("danger") and also change from "alert" to success where temp.closest("div").classList.remove("alert"); should be "success" or at least that's what I think :D but still unsuccessful. Debugger give me error here : if (parseInt(this.responseText)) > 30) {  - uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>'

Comment: not much of a luck either :(

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239835/discussion-between-svet-geoff-and-mplungjan).

Comment: hey @mplungjan i'm trying to do things in both ways like so:  const div = document.getElementById("temperature"), temp = this.responseText;
      div.innerHTML = temp;
      div.closest(".alert.alert-success").style.backgroundColor= temp>28?"#F8D7DA": "#D4EDDA";
       div.closest(".alert.alert-success").style.backgroundColor= temp<18?"#F8D7DA": "#D4EDDA"; } where is my error?

Comment: Please look at updated code